# How to increase number of saved session in MobaXTrem Portable version

Tags: putty, mobaxterm

Is there a way to increase the number of sessions we can save in the MobaXTerm Portable version, default is ~ 10.

Comment: Tried playing around ini file, looks like it just reads/considers the first 14 entries under bookmarks

Comment: you need the professional edition https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/download.html

Comment: Yeah was kinda hoping to avoid that, thanks.